# Binding a static objects property which is changed by a separate thread to a label in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm currently trying to update a label in a WPF project to display the status of a TCP server. The text box will bind to the property on startup and correctly show in the label, however i'm struggling to find a way to notify that the property has changed from another thread and update the label.

```
private void startServerMultiThread() 
    {
        try
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(() => MultiThreadedListener.startListening());
            t.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            showErrors(e);
        }
    }
```

Within MultiThreadedListener.startListening(), Status.ServerStatus is set to true after starting a new TCP listener.

```
public class Status
{
    public static EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs> StaticPropertyChanged;

    private static bool _ServerStatus = false;
    public static bool ServerStatus
    {
        get { return _ServerStatus; }

        set
        {
            if (value != _ServerStatus)
            {
                _ServerStatus = value;

                NotifyStaticPropertyChanged("ServerStatus");
            }
        }
    }
    private static void NotifyStaticPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (StaticPropertyChanged != null)
            StaticPropertyChanged(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

I've stepped through and found that my EventHandler is always null when ServerStatus is updated and also receiving a binding error:

```
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=TabStripPlacement; DataItem=null; target element is 'TabItem' (Name='serverMainTab'); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')
```

My XAML for the label:

```
<Window x:Class="serverGUI.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:serverGUI"
    xmlns:server="clr-namespace:server;assembly=server"

    Title="MainWindow" Height="386" Width="418">
<Grid>
    <TabControl x:Name="serverTabControl">
        <TabItem x:Name="serverMainTab" Header="Server"  Margin="-2,-2,2,0">
            <Grid>
                <!-- SERVER STATUS -->
                <Label Content="Status:" Margin="10,10,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="26" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="94"/>
                <Label x:Name="server_status" Content="{Binding Path=(server:Status.ServerStatus)}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,14,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="155" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
            </Grid>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

How would I go about making sure the WPF application is listening for events on alternate threads? is this even the correct approach to this problem or do I need to look at an alternative way? Thanks for any help.

Comment: The data binding error message is not related to your ServerStatus binding. Do you at least see an initial "false" in the server_status Label?

Comment: Yeah, false will show when the program first loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `event` keyword in the StaticPropertyChanged event declaration.

It should be

```
public static event EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs> StaticPropertyChanged;
```

instead of

```
public static EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs> StaticPropertyChanged;
```

Comment: Thank you, works now. Don't know how I managed to overlook such a silly mistake.